# Add more labels to a stacked column chart in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

I have this chart in SSRS 2008 R2

[image: stacked column with total]

I added the red numbers with mspaint to show what I want to do. Is there a way to add a total of each stacked column?

Comment: http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/65/posts/11575/display-total-on-top-of-stacked-chart.aspx

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/654f30c2-ad3a-4b4e-a34f-adf4db6b78d2/stacked-column-chart-total?forum=sqlreportingservices